# Persistent Virtualbox guest VM hardware configuration

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I wish move to virtual Windows on my corporate laptop, rather to keep it as host OS.
I will use this VM Windows on few laptops, but because this will be fully original OS version with Office and serial number, I want to make sure that running VM on first, second and then again on first one, won't lead to a need of activating again this VM Windows.
My question is as follows:
If I run VM Windows copy on multiple laptops, can I be sure that this virtual Windows will alway have the same hardware ? I mean running it on laptop with i5, then on i7 host won't lead to some "hardware changes" in virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work with WinXP and (probably) won't with Windows 7.

I need to run Internet Explorer to access bank information and run this from a VM. I have a copy of that on my server, in case I have broken my workstation setup. The workstation and server used to have the same motherboard and (AMD) processor (although at different speeds) and things worked fine for both WinXP and Win7 (i.e. I could choose whatever machine I wanted).

After replacing both motherboards (different motherboards and diffent AMD CPUs) this is no longer the case, the same VMs needed to be activated for Windows 7 **and the activated** VM moved to the other machine did need reactivation.

I haven't tried with Windows 8 or 9 (10?), I have read that things are slightly less restrictive with those versions of Windows. I would run WinXP for this, but the bank doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Details needed - did you move all VM configuration between those machines ? I mean VM machine configuration files between these two host machines too ? I'm asking because I'm not sure how cloud services do that as I doubt each machine has the same configuration and IDs for hardware components. Also, I remember having imaging VM machine in previous job, that we used in previous job, and there was no problem moving VM from one to other host. The only differences were Win2003 and VLK copy (volume licence copy). Under VLK licensing program and W2003 there was no need for further activation.
Reactivation ? - I just found some clue, that in your example, this could be related to different configuration files for VM machine - different disk and machine UUID. Anthony, try to move also all .xml confiuration files. I will also do so, when I'm back home from Berlin and will leave some summary here.